# Performing Like % between 2 columns in different DB2 tables.

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Trying to Achieve the below in SQLRPGLE program(I series) on DB2

I have a table(Table A) with 10 fields which are 10 search criteria's for the Item description field(in the Item master, ITMMST file).10 search Criteria's of Table A would contain values like 'ABC%', 'IND%' etc
 Now, I want to check for all the items in ITMMST, if the Item Desc field field contains any of those search criteria.

I tried to do like % against Table A but it did not work. I also tried to give Like % in the 'ON' of Inner join between Table A and ITMMST but that also did not work.

Putting the 10 criteria into Program Fields also would not work as there may be multiple records in Table A and I have to check all 10 fields for all the records.

THe only way I can think of is to have a cursor on Table A, and read it record by record(By retrieving the values into program Fields) for each Item Description and then check using 'Like'. But this would take a Hit on the performance as ITMMST is a Huge table.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You have left out a lot of detail such as what if a criteria field in A is blank, what if more than one record in A matches a single record in the master. I will answer assuming that blank criteria are to be ignored, and duplicates are to be suppressed.

```
select distinct * 
  from ITMMST
  cross join TABLEA
  where (description like criteria1 and criteria1 <> '')
     or (description like criteria2 and criteria2 <> '')
     ...
     or (description like criteria10 and criteria10 <> '')
```

Not sure how well this will perform, but the optimizer will do it's best with the indexes provided, or it will tell you how to make better indexes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark! I did get another solution which I have posted here

Answer (score 0):

Build your SQL Statement dynamically and then execute immediate.  Something like

```
Statement = 'select (column list) from ITMMST where Description like (' + CompareField1 + ')';
exec sql execute immediate :Statement;
```

Just add as many compares as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I did think of that.. But there could be multiple records and I have to search in all the records for the 10 Compare fields.. I guess this would work if there is only one record where I will be searching? Looks like I will have to go through all the records in a cursor..

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is susceptible to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for All Your Help.. 
I figured out a way to do this .

```
selECT * FROM ITMMST A                       
INNER JOIN(                                                         
SELECT TRIM(Criteria1) AS SPARM FROM TableA WHERE TRIM(WMSCT1) <> ''   
UNION ALL                                                           
SELECT TRIM(Criteria2) AS SPARM FROM TableA WHERE TRIM(WMSCT2) <> ''   
UNION ALL                                                           
SELECT TRIM(Criteria3) AS SPARM FROM TableA WHERE TRIM(WMSCT3) <> ''   
UNION ALL                                                           
SELECT TRIM(Criteria4) AS SPARM FROM TableA WHERE TRIM(WMSCT4) <> ''   
UNION ALL                                                           
SELECT TRIM(Criteria5) AS SPARM FROM TableA WHERE TRIM(WMSCT5) <> ''   
UNION ALL                                                           
SELECT TRIM(Criteria6) AS SPARM FROM TableA WHERE TRIM(WMSCT6) <> '' ) ..........
AS SLIST                                                            
ON A.ITEM_DESC Like SLIST.SPARM
```